# Will changing my Facebook app's namespace reset likes, etc?

Tags: facebook, namespaces, facebook-page

Will changing my Facebook app's namespace reset likes, etc?

My page has over 30k likes but I'm still using the default URL `http://facebook.com/[random string]`. I'd like to use a custom namespace, I'm just afraid that it will cause:

1. Loss of likes
2. Other unknowns related to mobile app functionality.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you asking about `Facebook pages` or `Facebook apps`? because `http://facebook.com/[random string]` seems to be like a URL, it's page no, you can have your own username and it wont effect likes or anything on your page

Comment: It's an "App Page" - that's what it says just under the page avatar.

Comment: It wont effect anything :) head to https://www.facebook.com/username ,select your page and choose an available username and your done with your SEO friendly permalink

Comment: Awesome, thanks Adam! Just wanted to be sure and prevent myself from doing something stupid.